# Python urllib2, Website says cookies not enabled

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, web-scraping, urllib2

Im trying to make scrape a website, but when I log in, it says cookies not enabled and restricts access. Here is my code, is there anything wrong with it?

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from cookielib import CookieJar
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

url = 'https://pamet-sapphire.k12system.com/CommunityWebPortal/Welcome.cfm'

# Prepare the data
query_args = { 'j_username':'username', 'j_password':'pass', 'j_pin':'pin' }

# This urlencodes your data (that's why we need to import urllib at the top)
data = urllib.urlencode(query_args)

# Send HTTP POST request

response = opener.open(url, data)
print cj 

print response.info()

html = response.read()

# Print the result
print html
```

Comment: could you please print the returned response using print r and tell me whats the answer?

Comment: @user12321 What do you mean by print r? printing response gives:
'<addinfourl at 38109952 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x02455370>>'